# How can I download files from Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm browsing my instance, `https://instance.sharepoint.com/1234/abc`

That page contains a list of several folders and files. How do I download files from that path?

```
    ClientContext cxt = new ClientContext(fullWebUrl);
    cxt.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, new NetworkCredential("", password).SecurePassword);

    List list = cxt.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

    cxt.Load(list);
    cxt.ExecuteQuery();

    FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;

    List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();

    foreach (Folder f in fcol)
    {
        if (f.Name == "filename")
        {
            cxt.Load(f.Files);
            cxt.ExecuteQuery();
            FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCol)
            {
                lstFile.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

This fails down at the foreach with the error

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException: 'The collection has not been initialized
```

Would not `cxt.ExecuteQuery` do the job?

Comment: Something looks wrong with `list.RootFolder.Folders`. Drop a breakpoint on your foreach, what's the value of `fcol`?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a mass download from a SharePoint library without using code, just do the following:

1:go to your SharePoint Library

2:copy the full path
for example

https://sharepointdomain.com/sites/yoursite/yourLibraryName/forms/Allitems.aspx

now remove

/forms/allitems.aspx from the address and you will remain with

https://sharepointdomain.com/sites/yoursite/yourLibraryName

copy that and open your windows file browser and paste that in the address bar and your library will be opened as a local folder, then you can select all files and copy them to any destination even you can move them to another SharePoint library you might be prompted to enter your SharePoint credentials make sure to enter it is as follow:
username is : domain\your SharePoint user name
password : your SharePoint login password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the FolderCollection fcol first (cxt.Load(fcol)):

```
      List list = cxt.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

      cxt.Load(list);
      cxt.ExecuteQuery();

      FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
      cxt.Load(fcol);
      cxt.ExecuteQuery();
      List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();

      foreach (Folder f in fcol)
      {
        if (f.Name == "filename")
        {
          cxt.Load(f.Files);
          cxt.ExecuteQuery();
          FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;

          foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCol)
          {
            lstFile.Add(file.Name);
          }
        }
      }
```

To download the file:

```
 foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCol)
  {
    var localstream = System.IO.File.Open("c:/" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
    var fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(cxt, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
    var spstream = fileInfo.Stream;
    spstream.CopyTo(localstream);
  }
```